# Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to configurate NEST from c# code
When I use Kibana command `GET /_cat/indices?v`

I get this result:

[image]

My test index is "customer"

I'm using Elasticsearch.Net and NEST: the .NET clients [6.x]
Elastic "6.5.4",
Now this is how I configurate on C#:

```
  var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
.DefaultIndex("customer");

        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);



        var newCustomer = new Customer
        {
            name = "test_name",
            OS = "test_os",
            script = "test_script"
        };


        var indexResponse = client.IndexDocument(newCustomer);
```

and I get an error:

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /customer/customer
```

why does it build request to /customer/customer ???
What am I configurating wrong?

**Error message:**

Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /customer/customer
Audit trail of this API call:
 -  BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.2817669
OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (400) Недопустимый запрос.. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /customer/customer. ServerError: Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "Rejecting mapping update to [customer] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, customer]" ---> System.Net.WebException: Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (400) Недопустимый запрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already a mapping in ES and the document you want to index doesnot match with it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this any further?

Answer (score 1):

> why does it build request to /customer/customer ??? What am I configurating wrong?

It builds it to `customer` (index) and `customer` (type) because

1. the index request does not specify an index into which the document should be indexed, so the request uses the [configured default index from `ConnectionSettings`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index-name-inference.html)
2. the index request does not specify a type for the document so [NEST infers the type name](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/types-and-relations-inference.html) from the POCO type name, by lowercasing it.

If you want to set a default type name for all POCOs, you can use

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
    .DefaultIndex("customer")
    .DefaultTypeName("_doc"); // <--- type name used for all POCOs
```

Comment: "DefaultTypeName" does not exist in the latest version of the NEST library

Comment: Correct, this is for 6.x, which the question asker is using