# Invalid NEST response from Elasticsearch request - invalid document formatting

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm getting started with the Elasticsearch NEST API [(I saw this post related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54146686/invalid-nest-response-built-from-a-unsuccessful-low-level-call-on-post)), and I'm trying to figure out what may be wrong with my query/object.

Here is my document object:

```
public class Jenson_Elastic_Log
    {
        public string exception { get; set; }
        public string http_context { get; set; }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(MyDateTimeConverter))]
        public DateTime log_date { get; set; }
        public string log_level { get; set; }
        public string logger { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string server_name { get; set; }
    }
```

The code that I'm using to query the index:

```
 var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200/")).DefaultIndex("jenson_logging");

        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var testLog = new Jenson_Elastic_Log
        {
            exception = "test",
            http_context = "local",
            log_date = DateTime.Now,
            log_level = "High",
            logger = "testing",
            message = "test push log",
            server_name = "localhost"
        };


        var indexResponse = client.IndexDocument(testLog);
        var asyncIndexResponse =  client.IndexDocument(indexResponse);
```

This keeps throwing the error: "{Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (400) low level call on POST: /jenson_logging/_doc}" (the error comes up with/without the datetimeconverter present)

Here is what my json object looks like for the index I'm trying to query against:

https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.ff3388575dc945688a446884bfcf1814

Any assistance in getting the querying to this object would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you share `MyDateTimeConverter`class and index mapping?

Answer (score 0):

My *suspicion* is the index `"jenson_logging"` contains an existing doc mapping that is not `"_doc"`, which results in a 400 Bad Request when attempting to index a document with the 7.x client. You should be able to get more details about what the error is by looking at the [`indexResponse.DebugInformation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html).

The 7.x client does not expose a way to send any other doc type other than `"_doc"` because [types are deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in future](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/removal-of-types.html). Other systems indexing into Elasticsearch *may* still set a different doc type in 7.x other than `"_doc"`, but I would **strongly recommend** changing these to use `"_doc"` as it will prepared in the case the cluster is upgraded to a new major version in the future.

An aside, the [`JsonNetSerializer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer) needs to be hooked up in order to support `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyDateTimeConverter))]` on the POCO.